simplify $(A^{c}\cap C)\cup(A\cap C)$ using set identities
so I've been trying to solve this for an hour, I need to simplify the following using set identities but for life of me i can't do it
$$(A^c\cap C) \cup (A \cap C) = C$$
so for I've applied the distributive law witch gave me
$$((A^c \cap C) \cup A) \cap ((A^c \cap C)\cup C) = C$$
but I'm not even sure that helps

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Apply the distributive law in reverse:
$$(C \cap A^c) \cup (C \cap A) = C \cap (A^C \cup A)$$
Can you continue?

omg I can't believe I missed that darn I'm really not good at this, anyway I was able to move one from there and solve the problem thank you for all your help.
